# Using variable for an identifier name (using jquery selectors)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Believe me, I've been looking for examples online for hours. None of them seem to help.

I'm working on making a table. There are some columns with dropdown menu and I've assigned ID to each menu. Inside a loop, I'm trying to assign selected value for each dropdown menu.

```
var row$ = $('<tr/>');
function updateDataBodyGenerator(myList) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        var colIndex = 0;

        for (var key in myList[i]) {

            var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
            if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
            var severityDropDownMenu = "severityDropDownMenu" + i;
            colIndex++;
            switch (key) {
                case "Test Case":
                    ...
                    break;
                case "Test Result":
                    ...
                    break;
                case "Severity":
                    var severitySting = '<td><select id="' + severityDropDownMenu + '" class="dropDownMenu">' +
                        '<option value="Red">Red</option>' +
                        '<option value="Green">Green</option>'+
                        '<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>';

                    row$.append($(severitySting));

                    //failed
                    //$("#severityDropDownMenu" + i).val(cellValue);

                    //failed
                    //var selectorString = "#" + severityDropDownMenu.toString();
                    //$(selectorString).val("Green");

                    //failed
                    //$("#" + severityDropDownMenu).val(cellValue);

                    //failed
                    //var selectorString = '#' + severityDropDownMenu;
                    //$(selectorString).val(cellValue);

                    //works
                    //$('#severityDropDownMenu0').val(cellValue);

                    ...
```

As you can see in the comments, I've tried several approaches and only 1 worked which was $('#severityDropDownMenu0').val(cellValue); but that will only change 1 dropdown menu.

I appreciate your time and assistance.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see how any of these would work.  I don't see where you are appending the `row$` to the body so it would be available for `$()` to find.

Comment: No matter which way you do it, `$("#severityDropDownMenu" + i)` wont select your element because its is not in the page DOM, it is appended to your `$('<tr/>')` object (row$), which itself isnt in the page DOM. You can do `row$.find("#severityDropDownMenu" + i)` to access it though

Comment: If you changed severityString to be a jquery object, then you could find('select') on it to change it's value before appending that object to the row.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thank you!! That worked! I appreciate it.

Comment: Why not just make it selected via the html you're generating? then you won't even need the id.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're trying to use the `#` selector to target the dropdown by ID.

The issue here (as mentioned in the comments) is that this selector will search the DOM for the element, however because you've never added this element to the DOM, it doesn't exist on the page; the selector will return nothing.

What you can do instead is actually turn your `severitySting` into a jQuery element to set its value. Whenever you *do* append it, the value will be properly set. Like so:

```
var $severity = $(severitySting);         //This is the <td>
var $dropdown = $severity.find("select")  //This is the <select>
$dropdown.val(cellValue);                 //Set dropdown value
```

---

**Demo:**

```js
var severityDropDownMenu = "mytest";
var cellValue = "Yellow";
var severitySting = '<td><select id="' + severityDropDownMenu + '" class="dropDownMenu">' +
    '<option value="Red">Red</option>' +
    '<option value="Green">Green</option>' +
    '<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>';

var $severity = $(severitySting);
var $dropdown = $severity.find("select");
$dropdown.val(cellValue);

$("tr").append($severity);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```